# What is the sectional curvature of this explicitely given n-dimensional submanifold of R^(n+1)?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Let $n>1$ be an integer. Consider $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ with the coordinates $x_1,\ldots,x_n,y$ and the closed submanifold
$$
M_n := \left\{ (x_1,\ldots,x_n,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\ \mid\ y \sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2 = 1\right\}.
$$
Since it is a submanifold of Euclidean space with its canonical flat metric, $M_n$ becomes a Riemannian manifold. I want to compute its sectional curvature (for a given point $(x,y)\in M_n$ and a two vectors $v,w\in T_{(x,y)}M_n$), but do not know how to proceed. For $n=2$, sectional curvature is the same as usual Gaussian curvature and I found a formula for computing it, but for higher dimensions my differential geometry skills are not enough.
It is clear that $M_n$ is the graph of a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ and it is "rotational invariant", in the sense that the value of the curvature at a point $(x,y)$ should only depend on $\|x\|=\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2}$, but I don't know if that is of any help.

What I would expect to happen is that the sectional curvature is everywhere non-positive.
But I would like to know wether the sectional curvature of the manifold is bounded below (I would guess yes, because that is what happend for $n=2$) and whether there is a lower bound that does not depend on $n$ (I have no idea what to guess here).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How much do you know about sectional curvature and the second fundamental form?

Comment: This can be computed by first computing the second fundamental form and using the Gauss equations, which provide formulas for the components of the Riemann curvature in terms of the components of the second fundamental form. One way to proceed is to first derive the formula for the second fundamental form of a graph $$ M = \{ (x^1, \dots, x^n, y)\ :\ y = f(x^1, \dots, x^n) \} $$ and apply it to your specific example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Two}{\mathsf{I}\mathsf{I}}$
$\newcommand{\rD}{\mathrm{D}}$
You can use the second fundamental form and the [Gauss-Codazzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_fundamental_form) equation. For embedded manifolds in a vector space, the Gauss-Codazzi equation reads:
$$R_{vw}w.v = \Two(v, v). \Two(w, w) - \Two(v,w). \Two(v,w)
$$
and the sectional curvature is
$$sec(v, w) = \frac{R_{vw}w.v}{(v.v)(w.w) - (v.w)^2}.
$$
The formula for the second fundamental form with the embedded metric is simply $$\Two(v, w) = (\rD_v\Pi)w = (\rD_w\Pi)v$$
where $\Pi$ is the metric compatible projection to the tangent space. The second fundamental form is a covariant derivative of the projection, but it just works out to that directional derivative if you use the embedded metric in a vector space.

Let $z = (x, y)$ satisfying the defining equation and $C(z) = yx^Tx-1$, then its Jacobian is
$$J:\omega=(\omega_x, \omega_y) \mapsto  2y(x^T\omega_x)+ \omega_yx^Tx
 $$
or in matrix form $J$ is the $1\times (n+1)$ matrix $(2yx^T, x^Tx)$
$$\Pi(z)\omega = \omega - J^T(JJ^T)^{-1}J\omega.$$
Here, $JJ^T = |J|^2 = 4y^2x^Tx + (x^Tx)^2$
$$\Pi(z)\omega = \begin{bmatrix}\omega_x\\ \omega_y\end{bmatrix}
  - \frac{2y(x^T\omega_x)+ \omega_yx^Tx}{4y^2x^Tx + (x^Tx)^2}\begin{bmatrix}2yx\\ x^Tx\end{bmatrix} $$
if $v=(v_x, v_y), w = (w_x, w_y)$ are two tangent vectors then
$$\Two(v, w) =- \frac{2v_y(x^Tw_x)+
  2y(v_x^Tw_x) + 2 w_yx^Tv_x}{4y^2x^Tx + (x^Tx)^2}\begin{bmatrix}2yx\\ x^Tx\end{bmatrix}
  $$
noting that since $w$ is a tangent vector, when you take directional derivative, any term that leaves the Jacobian intact will evaluate to zero. From here, you can evaluate the sectional curvature. You can simplify using $v_y =-\frac{2yx^Tv_x}{x^Tx}$.

See https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.10017 for some other examples of this type of calculation.

As this type of question appears quite often, let's give a general answer. If a hypersurface $M$ is given by a level set equation $\phi(x) = C$ in an inner product space $E$ with $\phi$ is a scalar function, let $g_{\phi}$ be its gradient and $hess_{\phi}$ be its hessian, consider as a bilinear form, so $hess_{\phi}(\xi, \eta)$ is a number for two vectors $\xi, \eta$. Then under the embedded metric

1. The Levi-Civita connection is
   $$\nabla_XY = D_XY + \frac{hess_{\phi}(X, Y)}{|g_{\phi}|^2}g_{\phi}$$
   Here, two vector fields $X, Y$ on $M$ are considered as vectors in $E$, and $D_XY$ is the flat connection on $E$, ie simple Lie derivative.
2. The second fundamental form is $-\frac{hess_{\phi}(X, Y)}{|g_{\phi}|^2}g_{\phi}$.
3. The sectional curvature numerator is
   $$R_{XY}Y.X = \frac{1}{|g_{\phi}|^2} \{hess_{\phi}(X, X)hess_{\phi}(Y,Y)- hess_{\phi}(X, Y)^2\}.
   $$

Proof: For 1, the right hand side is a vector field, as differentiating $g_{\phi}^ . Y = 0$ using $X$, we get
$$hess_{\phi}(X, Y) + g_{\phi}. D_XY = 0$$
which implies $g_{\phi}. \{D_XY + \frac{hess_{\phi}(X, Y)}{|g_{\phi}|^2}g_{\phi}\} =0$, it satisfies the usual conditions of a covariant derivative, and metric compatibility follows from
$$2Y . (D_XY + \frac{hess_{\phi}(X, Y)}{|g_{\phi}|^2}g_{\phi}) = 2Y . D_XY= D_X (Y. Y)
$$
as $Y.g_{\phi} = 0$.

For 2, it is well-known $\nabla_XY = \Pi D_XY$ if $\Pi$ is the metric-compatible projection, hence $\Two(X, Y) = D_XY - \Pi D_XY = 
D_XY - \nabla_XY=-\frac{hess_{\phi}(X, Y)}{|g_{\phi}|^2}g_{\phi} $. The Gauss-Codazzi equation gives 3.

Comment: Thank you for this nice answer. I will try to work through the details and then accept it, when I understood it (or when I gave up trying to understanding it, but it still sounds nice ;-) )

Comment: $\newcommand{\Two}{\mathsf{II}}$ 
Another way to derive the SFF is to use the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_fundamental_form)
$$\Two(v, w) = - ( D_v\nu . w ) \nu
$$
where $\nu$ is the Gauss map, so $\nu = \frac{1}{|grad_{\phi}|}grad_{\phi}$, thus
$$D_v\nu .w  = \{D_v(\frac{1}{|grad_{\phi}|})grad_{\phi} 
+ \frac{1}{|grad_{\phi}|} D_v grad_{\phi}\} . w
= \frac{1}{|grad_{\phi}|} hess_{\phi}(v, w)
$$
where $grad_{\phi}.w=0$ in the first summand, as $w$ is a tangent vector, and we again have $\Two(v, w) = -\frac{hess_{\phi}(v, w)}{|grad_{\phi}|^2}grad_{\phi}$.

Comment: I did a lot of calculations and - using your formulas - arrived at the conclusion that at a point $(x,y)\in M \subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$, the sectional curvature is $\frac{4}{(4+r^6)r^2}(1+4\cos^2\alpha+4\cos^2\beta)$, where $r=\| x\|$ and $\alpha$ is the angle between x and the first n comonents of the first vector spanning my 2dim subspace of the tangent space, similarly $\beta$ corresponds to the second vector. The problem is: This contradicts my previous computation of the Gauss-curvature in $n=2$, where I got $-\frac{12 r^4}{(4 + r^6)^2}$ ... I am confused ... :-/

Comment: The Gauss-curvature is always below 0 but tends to 0 when r goes to 0. My sectional curvature is always above 0 and goes off to infinity when r approaches 0. I assume I did a stupid calculation mistake somewhere, but so far I could not find it ...

Comment: Thanks! Will check

Comment: Okay, I think I found my mistake. I forget the denominator of the sectional curvature because I thought it would be zero. Now, the formula looks more similar to the Gauss-curvature but the sign is still wrong. And for my original question: It looks as if the section curvature is no longer bounded as soon as n>=3 , which is quite unexpected ...

Comment: Onething when you use these $R^{n+1}$ formulas is for a tangent vector, $(\Delta_x, \Delta_y)$ you have $\Delta_y = -\frac{2yx^T\Delta_x}{x^Tx}$, and you probably need to use this to convert everything to $\Delta_x$. Will get back in a bit.

Comment: For  $\phi(x, y) = yx^Tx$, the Hessian is
$$2w_yx^Tv_x + 2yw_x^Tv_x + 2v_yx^Tw_x
=-\frac{8x^Tv_xx^Tw_x}{(x^Tx)^2} +\frac{2v_x^Tw_x}{x^Tx}
$$
for $v=(v_x, v_y=-\frac{2yx^Tv_x}{r^2}), w=(w_x, w_y=-\frac{2yx^Tw_x}{r^2})$, replacing $y=\frac{1}{x^Tx}$.

Comment: The gradient is $(\frac{2}{x^Tx}x, x^Tx)$
Thus, the numerator and denominator are

$$N = \frac{4}{(4x^Tx+ (x^Tx)^4)}\{(-\frac{4}{x^Tx}(xv_x)^2 + |v_x|^2)(-\frac{4}{x^Tx}(xw_x)^2 + |w_x|^2)
         -(-\frac{4}{x^Tx}(x.v_x)(x.w_x) + v_x.w_x)^2 \}\\
D = ((v_x^Tv_x) + \frac{4(x^Tv_xx^Tv_x)}{(x^Tx)^{4}})
 ((w_x^Tw_x) + \frac{4(x^Tw_xx^Tw_x)}{(x^Tx)^{4}})
  - ( ((v_x^Tw_x) + \frac{4(x^Tv_xx^Tw_x)}{(x^Tx)^{4}})
  )^2.$$
If the tangents are such that $x^Tv_x=0 = x^Tw_x$ we have curvature $\frac{4}{4x^Tx + (x^Tx)^4}$, when $x^Tx = r^2$ goes to infinity, the curvature goes to zero.